# Ternary operator to return value- Java/Android

Tags: java, android, function, operators, ternary-operator

Just switched to Java from php

I encountered following issue

I want to rewrite

```
if(usrname.equals(username) && (passwd.equals(password))){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

as

```
(usrname.equals(username) && passwd.equals(password) )? return true : return false;
```

it is not working(syntax error)
however,

```
int a=1;
int b=2;
int minVal = a < b ? a : b;
```

is working

**Why ternary operator are not behaving correctly  while returning value depending on some condition**

EDIT

```
return  (usrname.equals(username) && passwd.equals(password));
```

could be solution if it return boolean .

lets say i need

```
 (usrname.equals(username) && passwd.equals(password) )? return "member": return "guest";
```

Comment: `return usrname.equals(username) && (passwd.equals(password)` ?

Comment: Try this : String  b = (usrname.equals(username) && passwd.equals(password) )?  "member":  "guest";

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do

```
return (usrname.equals(username) && passwd.equals(password) )?  true : false;
```

`true` and `false` can be replaced by any return value you want. If it is just boolean then you can avoid ternary operator altogether. Just do

```
return  (usrname.equals(username) && passwd.equals(password));
```

Answer (score 27):

> lets say I need
>
> ```
>   (usrname.equals(u) && passwd.equals(p)) ? return "member" : return guest";
> ```

The correct syntax is:

```
   return (usrname.equals(u) && passwd.equals(p)) ? "member" : "guest";
```

---

The general form of the ternary operator is

```
   expression-1 ? expression-2 : expression-3
```

where `expression-1` has type `boolean`, and `expression-2` and `expression-3` have the same type<sup>1</sup>.

In your code, you were using `return` statements where expressions are required.  In Java, a `return` statement is NOT a valid expression.

<sup>1 - This doesn't take account of the *conversions* that can take.  For the full story, refer to the JLS.</sup>

---

Having said that, the best way to write *your* example doesn't uses the conditional operator at all:

```
   return usrname.equals(username) && passwd.equals(password);
```

Answer (score 5):

Why redundant `boolean`

Just use

```
return  (usrname.equals(username) && passwd.equals(password));
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way you can simplify:

return (usrname.equals(username) && passwd.equals(password) )? return true : return false;

To:

return usrname.equals(username) && passwd.equals(password);

The ternary operator work similar in php than Java, I think you have made a silly mistake, maybe "username" have a space or another white character

```
String a1 = "a";
String b1 = "b";

String a2 = "a";
String b2 = "b";

System.out.println((a1.equals(a2)&&b1.equals(b2))?"true":"false");
```

it return "true"

Comment: Two other people have already said that.  And re your update, no that's not the problem.  The problem is that the OP got the syntax wrong.

Comment: :o I figured out, you can't  put the return inside the ternary operator. I haven't see that in your code the first time

Answer (score 0):

Java ternary operator is an expression, and is thus evaluated to a single value. 
As per the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html), for below given expression

```
result = someCondition ? value1 : value2;
```

if the boolean condition is true then assign the value of *value1* to the result, else assign *value2* to the result. Both value1 and value2 should be of same value type.

Hence the correct syntax of a return statement would be

```
return boolean_condition ? value_when_true : value_when_false
```