# When would you use the conditional operator in java (? :) instead of the if else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a piece of code that uses a conditional operator to compare the value of the variable x to 5:

```
(x >=5 ? x : -x)
```

What benefit is there to using a conditional operator over a regular if else statement?

Comment: And what in your opinion would be `-"SomeString"`?

Comment: If `x` is a `String` (You shouldn't compare Strings with `==` btw.), then what is `-x` supposed to be?

Comment: @QBrute You're correct. My mistake. I updated the question now to use equalTo instead, and changed -x to y. If it is -x (or y, now), it would associate to a second case, where the first case would be x. x could be defined in the beginning of the code as something like String x = "It is cheese" and String y = "It's not cheese. I don't know what it is".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ternary Operators Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219695/ternary-operators-java)

Comment: [Why doesn't this method work? Java ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16876698). [ternary operator not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17635940). [Java ternary operator (?:) doesn't work; second or third operand return boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19010399). [Ternary operator to return value- Java/Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25072706). [How to use ternary operator with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41871767) [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/798545)

Comment: What's stopping you from running your code to see if it works?

Answer (score 3):

Note that is `?:` is an **expression** - it returns a value which must be consumed

```
z  = (x >=5 ? x : -x)
```

The `if` construct in Java is **not** an expression (there are languages where it is) and does not return a value so in this sense they are **not** equivalent.

An example where they are equivalent is when the `if` options perform an assignment:

```
if("Cheese".equals(x)) {
    type = "Dairy";
} else {
    type = "Maybe not dairy";
}
```

this is the same as

```
type =  "Cheese".equals(x) ? "Dairy" : "Maybe not dairy";
```

You can nest `?:` to arbitrary depth but really shouldn't - it becomes quite difficult to read:

```
    List<String> cheeses  = Arrays.asList("Gouda", "Edam");
    String x= "Gouda";

    String type =  cheeses.contains(x) ? "Gouda".equals(x) ? "Yummy Gouda" : "Cheese - but not Gouda" : "Maybe not dairy";
```

Comment: True - amended answer for the safer approach

Comment: Cool they're the same. What if you want to nest another if inside of the first if? so if it equals Cheese, then it asks what kind of cheese? That's the part I'm stuck on. If converting that nested if to a conditional, without using if.

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator is not the equivalent of `if-else` in **EVERY** possible case. This is because both of possible results of using ternary operator are **return** values (e. g. simple printing to the console is not a return value so it can't be one of possible results in ternary operator).

Look, you can do it with `if-else`, but it's not possible with ternary operator:

```
if (x > 5) {
    System.out.println("Statement is true");
else {
    System.out.println("Statement is false");
}
```

You **can't** do it with ternary operator:

```
x > 5 ? System.out.println("Statement is true") : System.out.println("Statement is false");
```

When both of results of using ternary operator are considered as return values, they are then an equivalent of `if-else`.

Comment: System.out.println((x > 5) ? "Statement is true" : "Statement is false");

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be used, but off course in that case using `-x` doesn't make sense so it depends on what do you want to return when String is an input. You can do this:

`("Cheese".equals(x) ? <some object of expected type X> : <some other object of expected type X>)`

where `X` can be `String` on any other type. And remember to do `"string".equals(x)` instead of `x.equals("string")`. This prevents `NullPointerException`.

For primitive values you can use `==`, but for objects you need to use `equals` method. There are some edge cases when you can use `==` on `String`, but they are not relevant to your case I guess and you can read about it outside of this topic.

PS: Some answers talk about if else statement, but that's not what question is about.

> Can this be used like an if else on all accounts? For example, can you
>   compare strings with it?

I am pretty sure that by saying `like an if else` he means conditional operator which has `if else` like behaviour, not `if else` instruction itself.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it can be used in Java; however note that `x =="Cheese"` isn't the proper way to compare strings in Java, you want something like `"Cheese".equals(x)`.